# Polygon with Random Number of Sides

Tags: python

I am working on a small project that uses `Turtle` and `Random` to make a polygon with a random number of sides. I keep running into the error `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`.

Here is my code:

```
import turtle
import random


def draw_shape():
    r = random.randrange(50)
    for x in r:
        turtle.forward(50)
        turtle.left(360/r)


draw_shape()
```

Comment: `randrange()` returns a number, you probably want to do; `for x in range(r)`

Comment: Try to use a title which is descriptive of your problem, instead of explaining what your overall goal is.

Answer (score 0):

[`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) returns a single value, an `int`, which can't be iterated over --- as your error message describes.

What you want is,

```
for x in range(r):
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.left(360/x)
```